# Problemas ao remover row usando JS no Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, javascript-eventos

Tenho um cadastro de endereços dinâmico onde o usuário adiciona e remove os endereços dinamicamente. Cada row que é adicionada fica dentro da "div-enderecos".
Não estou conseguindo remover as rows ('form-group align-items-center row') usando o JS. estou usando um componente swal para exibir mensagens de alerta... Acredito que ela esteja roubando o foco e atrapalhando. Alguém sabe como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-enderecos">

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {   
                    <div class="form-group align-items-center row">
                        <div class="card card-shadow col-md-12 pl-0 pr-o pt-0 pb-0 border border-default">
                            <div class="card-block">
                            //Fields1
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block"> 
                            //Fields2
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block">  
                            //Fields3
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#div-enderecos").on("click", ".btn-remover-endereco", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        swal({
        title: "Tem certeza?",
        text: "Esta operação excluirá permanentemente este endereço.",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-warning",
        confirmButtonText: 'Sim, prosseguir!',
        cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {

            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();



        } else {
            swal("Cancelado", "Operação cancelada! :)", "error");
        }
    });

 })
```

Comment: Tavlez seu erro seja aqui `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();` será que não era melhor usar algum outro seletor? As vc tem um pai a mais ai hein...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `$(this)` dentro da função do Swal perde a referência. É necessário armazená-lo numa variável para poder usar dentro dessa função. Antes do Swal, coloque:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Agora a variável `$this` tem como referência o botão que disparou o evento. No `if`, em vez de fazer...

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
```

...usando esse tanto de `.parent()`, você pode chegar o elemento desejado diretamente com `.closest()`, usando o `$this` criado anteriormente:

```
$this.closest(".row").remove();
```

O código irá ficar desta forma:

```
$("#div-enderecos").on("click", ".btn-remover-endereco", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);

        swal({
        title: "Tem certeza?",
        text: "Esta operação excluirá permanentemente este endereço.",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-warning",
        confirmButtonText: 'Sim, prosseguir!',
        cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {

            $this.closest(".row").remove();

        } else {
            swal("Cancelado", "Operação cancelada! :)", "error");
        }
    });

 })
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sam!!!!!